# For loop comparing values

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm attempting to compare the ASCII values from a string in order to find if a letter exists or not, given a string. I'm iterating through using `charCodeAt` to access the ASCII values and then push into an array. The problem I'm encountering is when I attempt to compare the values inside the loop.

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  const result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result.push(str[i].charCodeAt(str[i]) - str[i].charCodeAt(str[i - 1]));
  }
  return result;
}

console.info(fearNotLetter("abce"));
```

When I try to access the prior character inside the loop nothing is ever returned. I know I must subtract 1 from the index in order to access the prior character, however using `charCodeAt` is proving problematic. How would one access the prior character in this case?

Comment: I believe it should be `str.charCodeAt(i)` and `str.charCodeAt(i-1)`. Do note that will fail when `i === 0`. See the documentation for [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

Comment: Your code does not match your description.

Comment: Also, you should start your for loop at `var( i = 1`... so that you don't call `str.charCodeAt(str[-1])` at your first loop iteration.

Answer (score -1):

if your purpose is just **"to find if a letter exists or not"**: `/[a-z]/i.test(str)`, which returns `true` or `false`. That's all.